# What test to use post hoc?

Tags: anova, references, post-hoc

I have several scenarios in which I would like to do post hoc tests, but I am unsure of what tests to do. These are two way anovas with some of the interactions as significant and some of the main effects are significant. I have tried to look online, but cannot seem to find a resource that has adequate information. Does anyone know of such a resource?

Comment: The absolute first thing you should do is draw an interaction plot. Don't be in such a hurry to test things. Find out what's going on first.

Answer (score 1):

As always, the correct procedure to use in statistics depends on the objective and assumptions. You'll need to ask yourself, what are you looking for and trying to do? You'll need to form post-hoc hyoothesis (ie. not planning beforehand), based on what you want to do in your study.

For example, if you want to compare the interactions, you might do something like:

H0: ....
   H1: ....
   ......

Each hypothesis tests the terms in a pair-wise fashion. You'll need to adjust the p-value. This is an example of multiple testing, which you can use a variety of methods, such as the false-discovery rate control.